# output all values that match index-match search key

Tags: google-sheets

For now ive managed to output 1 correct value for index match, but i cant seem to figure out how to output all of the matches. This is what I have tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(G25>=1,if(countifs(F$2:F,F25,D$2:D,"=7")>=1,INDEX(R:R, MATCH(F25,F:F,0)))))
```

[heres my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pP1u.png)

So for now, column S outputs only the first match in R:R, which ends in .com/?p=82056, but there is another value that matches the index-match criteria, ".com/?p=3432" that is not being output.

Im trying to get ".com/?p=82056" and ".com/?p=3432" or everything that matches to output in one cell. Ive wrapped it in an ArrayFormula hoping this might output an array, but no luck.

What is the correct way to do this?

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
=join(", ",filter(R$2:R,F$2:F=F25,D$2:D>7,R$2:R<>"",R$2:R<>R25))
```

This is it ^ its really just join and the filter with your conditions. The join keeps the output in one cell